# Configure Django logging - SQL and other messages

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm trying to configure a Django app's logging so that all SQL generated by Django's ORM is logged to sql.log, and all other logged messages by Django are logged to another file. My logging portion of setup.py looks like this:

```
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': ...
'handlers': {
    'logfile' : {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
        'filename': '.../django.log',
    'formatter': 'verbose',
    },
'sqlfile': {
    'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
        'filename': '.../sql.log',
        'formatter': 'simple',
    },
'apache_log': {
    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'formatter': 'verbose',
}
},
'loggers': {
'django': {
    'handlers': ['logfile', 'apache_log'],
    'propagate': True,
    'level': 'INFO',
},
'django.db': {
    'handlers': ['sqlfile'],
    'propagate': True,
        'level': 'DEBUG',
},
}
```

SQL is indeed getting logged to sql.log, but it's also getting logged to django.log, although I specifically set the loglevel on the 'django' logger to INFO.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe set `'propagate': False` for `'django.db'` will help?

Comment: But I want INFO messages from django.db to be logged along with INFO messages from all other django loggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `stalk` is right. Events logged to `django.db` are passed to handlers attached to the `django.db` logger, but will also be passed to handlers for `django` and the root logger unless `propagate` is set to `False` for the `django.db` logger. See [this diagram](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) for how loggers and handlers work.

With the setting of `propagate` to `False`, events logged to `django.db` will only be passed to the `sqlfile` handler.